# Facing issues while trying to measure high voltage at high frequency

Tags: rf, power-electronics, switch-mode-power-supply, power-engineering

In the attached circuit I am facing a strange issue. I am trying to measure the voltage across the spark gaps 1 and 2  which are about 1 and 2mm. To do that, I have made a simple led chain indicator (after high voltage accidentally killed one of my multi meters). The indicator first attenuates incoming ac high voltage by running through voltage divider, runs it through fast diode full bridge rectifier and then feeds it to a LED chain that shows me roughly the voltage range from 3v to 24v. I tested the indicator and it works nicely on 50Hz and 240 volts. But when I use it on the circuit across the spark gaps which has high voltage riding on high frequency, instead of showing the range, all of the LEDs get turned on dimly. I tried with 100:1, 1000:1 and even tried with a 5000:1 divider but it has no effect.

Then I tried a number of other things to attenuate the high voltage but nothing works. I made a contactless indicator using a capacitive antenna and transistor amplifier, and that had the same issue. I ran the high voltage through a low pass filter (parallel capacitor and series inductor) to block the high voltage spikes but nothing works.

Curiously this behavior continues even if I remove one end of the connection between voltage divider and main circuit and only one leg of it remains connected to the main circuit whereas the other leg is hanging free. Still all the LEDs get turned on dimly which I think is extremely odd.

I can guess the voltage in main circuit is around 3500 volt as spark gap is 1mm. I do not know its frequency though. I just want to measure the voltage or at least get an indication of its value but nothing seems to work. Is this happening due to RF interference ?

What is the best way to measure high voltage riding on a high frequency across the spark gaps or in general?[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to tell the resonant frequency of your secondary without knowing the details of the coupling coil, but it will likely be in the 100 kHz-1 MHz range.

At these frequencies, even very small capacitances have a low impedance.

For instance 1 nF@1 MHz has an impedance of ~160 Ω.

This means a simple resistive divider using high value resistors is not going to behave as you might expect, with stray capacitance dominating the resulting output. Similarly, even your "one ended connections", can lead to significant high frequency current flows due to stray capacitance to ground.

You best best is probably to explicitly recognize the dominant role of capacitance, and build a capacitive divider. For instance, 1 nF to your circuit and 1 uF down to ground, gives a 1:1000 division at the midpoint.